# Adding new user info to current old user accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, insert, where

Hey all so I have a database that has been up and running for a few months now. I had a request to add the users **First** and **Last** name as well as their **organization**.

This was easy enough to do for **NEW** users:

```
"INSERT INTO " +
    "aspnet_UsersAddition " +
        "(UserId, firstName, LastName, OrganizationID) " +
"VALUES " +
    "(" +
        "'" + genGUID + "'," +
        "'" + Params.firstName + "'," +
        "'" + Params.lastName + "'," +
        "" + Params.Params["Org"] +
    ")";
```

However, and this is the problem, is that **OLD** users who do not have that First/Last and organization associated with their account need to have those added to them.

I have tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO 
    aspnet_UsersAddition   
        (UserId, firstName, LastName, OrganizationID) 
VALUES 
    ('','','',1) 
WHERE 
    UserId = (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE Email = 'admin@admin.com');
```

But of course the above would not work since the **UserId** in the **aspnet_UsersAddition** was **non-excitant** when comparing it to the **aspnet_Membership UserId**. The only info I have access to on the page where I am calling this function is their **email** address and **user name**.

So I guess my question is - How do I add a new record using the users **GUID** [that needs to be looked up via email address or user name] so that I can add that info [UserId] to the new table [first/last and organization]?

**Note: The UserId is a Uniqueindentifier.**

Do I have to make separate query's

> Select old users GUID using their email address.
>
> Insert new record into new table with blanks other than the GUID.

in order to do this? Or is there a way to do this in one query?

The only query I can come up with is a 2 parter:

```
DECLARE @userGUID VARCHAR(50)
SET @userGUID = (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE Email = 'admin@admin.com')

INSERT INTO 
    aspnet_UsersAddition 
        (UserId, firstName, LastName, OrganizationID) 
VALUES 
    (Convert(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @userGUID), '', '', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't fully follow your question, if you could clarify it a little bit that would be helpful, regardless it sounds like you're looking for a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_UsersAddition
     (UserId, firstName, LastName, OrganizationID) 
SELECT 
     UserId, '', '', 1
FROM aspnet_Membership 
WHERE Email = 'admin@admin.com'
```

This will `INSERT` the `UserId` with blanks for the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields, and 1 for the `OrganizationID` field, into the new table from the old table, for the supplied email address.

Comment: Yep that works like I needed it to! Thanks for the help J.D.

Comment: @StealthRT Cool, np! `SELECT`ing a dataset is another way you can insert into a table, instead of using the `VALUES` keyword.